# Google Scripts: send email with GMail imported account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a script with Google Script to perform a multiple email send with personalized text inside the email body (like name and addresses).
Is it possible to send the emails with an imported account (in GMail) via script?

Thanks

Comment: what is "an imported account"?

Comment: In GMail you can send email with other account like alias... [https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use send method of GmailApp:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body

sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)

Sends an email message. The size of the email (including headers) may not exceed 20KB.

```
// The code below will send an email with the current date an time
 var now = new Date();
 GmailApp.sendEmail("mikemike@gmail.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString());
```

Also, GmailApp.sendEmail support send from your alias as well.

`sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` support use options to set `options.from = 'alias@domain.com'`, as  document saying:

> from: String, the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by getAliases()

Comment: Thank you for your answer... but the email sent from your script will send email from your account... instead I need to send email from an alias, like GMail permitts in this way: [https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

Comment: GmailApp.sendEmail support send from your alias as well. `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` support use options to set `options.from = 'alias@domain.com'`, as  document saying: the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by getAliases()